# Perl can't install Glib on Mac Big Sur

Tags: macos, perl, glib

I'm trying to install Gtk2 from CPAN on my Mac (Big Sur), but it requires Glib, and Glib install is failing.  The tail of the installer output is here:

```
echo Generating POD...
Generating POD...
"/usr/bin/perl" -I blib/lib -I blib/arch -MGlib::GenPod -MGlib \
        -e "add_types (qq(doctypes));  Glib::GenPod::set_copyright(qq/Copyright (C) 2003-2011 by the gtk2-perl team.\n\nThis software is licensed under the LGPL.  See L<Glib> for a full notice.\n/); Glib::GenPod::set_main_mod(qq(Glib));  xsdoc2pod(q(build/doc.pl), q(blib/lib), q(build/podindex));"
Can't load 'blib/arch/auto/Glib/Glib.bundle' for module Glib: dlopen(blib/arch/auto/Glib/Glib.bundle, 0x0001): open("", O_RDONLY) failed with errno=2 at /System/Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DynaLoader.pm line 197.
 at blib/lib/Glib/GenPod.pm line 21.
Compilation failed in require at blib/lib/Glib/GenPod.pm line 21.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at blib/lib/Glib/GenPod.pm line 21.
Compilation failed in require.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
make: *** [build/podindex] Error 2
FAIL
! Installing Glib failed. See /Users/principal/.cpanm/work/1626461722.68580/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
```

Retry with --force gives the same results.  The specified build.log file gives less detail than the console output above.

If I understand what it's telling me, it is that the GenPod.m module fails at the point where it is trying to "use Glib;".  But when I look at the specified search point (blib/arch/auto/Glib/Glib.bundle) there is such a file there.

I'm using the Mac-installed Perl (5.30) and have had no other issues installing via CPAN.  Any help would be appreciated.  I would even welcome knowing how to bypass the "GenPod" step, as having working code is better than having documentation.  The latest post I could find on the topic of Glib failing to install on Mac was four years ago in the El Capitan days, and the OP there was having an entirely different problem.

Comment: Have you tried to install `Gtk2` with perlbrew? I am able to install all the dependent modules with perlbrew perl version 5.32.0, macOS Big Sur 11.2.3. When I try to install `Gtk2` itself there are [some failed tests](https://pastebin.com/YRtKLUjk), I am not sure if it safe to force install the module yet.